# Copying hard-drive onto another machine

Tags: installation, mac

I have a Ubuntu machine (at work) and I have a macbook as well.

Is it possible to copy the entire operating system (on my work ubuntu machine) over to the hard drive on the Mac? I don't really care if it wipes off the mac osx.

Looking for any suggestions or tutorials, hopefully that won't destroy my entire work machine because then I would be screwed!!

Comment: The answer to "Is it possible to copy the entire operating system (on my work ubuntu machine) over to the hard drive on the Mac" is "Yes", but depending on your goal, it may or may not be what you want. Do you want to copy over a working Ubuntu installation (harder to do) or just make a backup of your Ubuntu files (this is easier)? Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: @roadmr Erm, the whole working operating system? So in theory, I would just copy it over, re-start the machine and it will boot the same operating system, files, libraries installed etc.. :)

Answer (score 0):

This website contains the information you are looking for. Clonezilla is a Free and Open-Source alternative to Norton Ghost.

http://clonezilla.org/